# Nearly all frontpage questions downvoted

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Of the 50 questions on the front page a few minutes ago, all but 4 have downvotes.  (Many also have upvotes, of course, and many have more upvotes than downvotes.)

This doesn't seem normal to me.  Is it normal?  If not, what is happening?

Comment: I noticed something similar a day or two ago, but didn't check the numbers at that time.

Comment: Many of the answers to these questions are getting downvoted, too, even though they are correct...what's going on?

Comment: And usually, it's the same number of down votes on each page. I encountered 2 more often than not.

Comment: That's the third time I encountered this in this week. But I doubt if anything can be done.

Comment: It would be good to supplement this with a screenshot.

Comment: I can confirm changed behaviour. For the last 6 days, the number of downvotes on questions per day has increased by more than 50%. I do not know what to make of this.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : There has to be several screenshots as some of them has positive net votes.

Comment: Related post: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20550/can-moderators-know-the-identity-of-non-serial-mass-downvoters

Comment: Let's just say that I have a fairly good idea who it was. The tools moderators have access to point in a certain direction (that just happens to be on my list of usual suspects). I'm not experienced enough in hunting down such patterns, so I wait for other moderators to take a look at the evidence. We may also need to ask CMs to take a look, because the mods don't have precise enough tools to find the smoking gun.

Comment: @mixedmath could you give a rough absolute number, too?

Comment: I just got "+2 User was removed", which happens rarely enough to be an evidence that someone took action on this.

Comment: Just discovered that a user was removed...... Um

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Do you know what ended up happening here?

Comment: The moderators agreed that the pair of users I suspected were behind this. One was a sock puppet of the other. I deleted the puppet and suspended the main account. If we nailed the right duo, then the deletion of the puppet should lead to +2s for many people who were initially hit with a downvote. Looks like that is exactly what happened! Note: I did not delete the puppeteer. I want to discuss the best course of action (re that user) with the SE staff. I will request them to annul the downvotes cast by that account, but need a bit more time to formulate that request. Sorry about the delay.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : No problem about the delay.  Thanks for letting us know what's going on.

Comment: The mills of the Mods grind slowly, but...

Comment: OTOH. If we are the detectives, prosecutors, members of the jury, the judge and the executioner could something possibly ever go wrong with that? Thankfully we're not in a criminal court. IMO a better analogue is that to a home plate umpire making the calls the best they see. "OUT!"

Comment: I also noticed it a couple of days ago. I thought it was just a bad day.

Comment: What reward do moderators get for the kind of good action indicated here?   Don't we need moderators who take action? When the next moderator elections come up, will we remember this and look for the right people? @JyrkiLahtonen part of a great team, and I'm sure there's lots we don't see.

Comment: @Mark: To prevent political games, moderators are elected until they leave on their own, or leave not on their own. But they do not get re-elected after a term (well, generally, I suppose someone stepping down for some reason can run again after some time if the reasons make sense). The moderators get our gratitude, although not from everyone, and mostly a lot of fire on when someone deleted a comment, locks a post, or un/delete something disputed. Then we like to forget that they too are people who do volunteer work for this community... at least until someone reminds that in the comments.